# How to check the CSV column consistency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have a CSV file like:

```
Header:  1,2,3,4
content: a,b,c,d,e
         a,b,c,d
         a,b
         a,b,c,d,d
```

Is there any CSV method that I can use to easily validate the column consistency instead of
parsing the CSV line by line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way or another the whole file has to be read.
Here is a relative simple way. First the file is read and converted to an array which is then mapped to another array based on length (number of fields per row). This array is the checked if the length is always the same.

If you'd hate to read the file twice you could remember the length of the header and while you parse the file check each record if it has the same number of fields and otherwise trow an exeption.

```
require "csv"

def valid? file
  a = CSV.read(file).map { |e|e.length  }
  a.min == a.max
end

p valid?("data.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

[csv_validator gem](https://github.com/mattfordham/csv_validator) would be helpful here.